# How to query, one to many relationship, denormalize

Tags: sql, oracle

I am sorry about the title, I am not sure how to ask. I have tables, entity and email, this is one to many relationship.

My code is

```
select e.pref_mail_name, em.email_address
from entity e
left join email em ON em.id_number = e.id_number
```

Then output is like this

```
pref_mail_name   --------------- em.email_address
jsmith                           jsmith@yahoo.com
El Alex                          EL@yahoo.com
EL ALex                          EL@Gmail.com
EL Alex                          EL@hotmail.com
Jay smith                        Jsm@gmail.com
```

I would like to show like this

```
  pref_mail_name ----em.email_address1---em.email_address2--em.email_address3
  jsmith             jsmith@yahoo.com
  El Alex            EL@yahoo.com        EL@Gmail.com      EL@hotmail.com 
  Jay smith          Jsm@gmail.com
```

How can I write a query to echo out like above?

Comment: Do you want to limit to 3 email adresses? If not you can use an aggregate function (`LISTAGG` or `XMLAGG`) to created a concatenated list of email addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want static columns, you can use the following method, which takes advantage of the lead function (you could also use lag and reverse the sorting):

```
select e.pref_mail_name, em.email_address1, em.email_address2, em.email_address3
from entity e
left join (
    select 
      id_number,
      rank() over (partition by id_number order by email_address asc) as email_rank,
      lead(email_address,0,null) over (partition by id_number order by id_number, email_address asc) as email_address1,
      lead(email_address,1,null) over (partition by id_number order by id_number, email_address asc) as email_address2,
      lead(email_address,2,null) over (partition by id_number order by id_number, email_address asc) as email_address3
    from email
 ) em 
    ON em.id_number = e.id_number
    AND em.email_rank = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  e.pref_mail_name
  ,max(case when rn=1 then email_address end) email_1
  ,max(case when rn=2 then email_address end) email_2
  ,max(case when rn=3 then email_address end) email_3
FROM entity e LEFT JOIN 
  (select email_address, id_number
          ,row_number() over (partition by id_number order by 2) rn from email) em
ON (e.id_number=em.id_number)
GROUP by pref_mail_name, 2;
```